# Android application which allows location selection through google maps

Tags: android, google-maps, select, location

I am trying to make an application which allows the user to select a location on google map(on the press of a button). It is not related to his current position. He can select any position he wants(I was reading into markers, some help on that will be greatly appreciated). After he selects the location, I want that location to be saved in a string format in my application, so that I can do further work with it. I have searched around a lot, but can't seem to find any which allows the user to select his location through gmaps and save it, all through another application. Please help!

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/interactivity#map_clicklong_click_events

Comment: I am kinda new to this, so please excuse that, so can you please list the overall process I can take?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your map is called myMap, i think it should be something like this.

```
myMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(new OnMapLongClickListener(){
    @Override 
    public void onMapLongClick(LatLng point) {
         //TODO Handle your code.

         //Add marker to map for clarity
         myMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(point).title("My Marker"));
     }
});
```